# Copy a row of values from a 1D array that represents a three dimensional grid

Tags: c#, java, arrays

So I have a 1D array representing a 3D grid of numbers, I access individual entries (X,Y,Z) like so:

```
array[x + width * (y + height * z)]
```

Is there a way I can copy out an entire row (for instance, all the Z values for (1,1)) without looping? I'd rather not use a jagged array if possible.

Comment: First of all, create a proper data model instead of using bizarre weird calculations, then, in C#, use a single, beautiful LINQ statement, in java, a bunch of horrible code because java is horrible.

Comment: Why a jagged (int[][][]) or multi-dimentional (int[,,]) arrays are not an option?  Why you don't want to loop?<br/>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I'm already looping through every entry. I want to save performance by checking for empty rows (all 0s) and skipping processing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function if you don't want to use a loop structure.